# What are the relevant Big O notations for linked lists?

Tags: computer-science

both single and double?

There should be a big O for inserting and finding elements in a linked list.

According to Columbia notes, for a single linked list, it is:

> Singly Linked List ( SSL ) An SLL is a series of nodes. Each node
>   contains data and a reference to the next node.  An SSL can grow and
>   shrink as needed. Adding an element to the list is O (1).   Finding an
>   element in the list is O (n).

Comment: Data structures do not have computational complexity; *operations* on data structures have computational complexity. Which operations are you asking about?

Comment: What do you actually  want to know ?

Comment: Do you see any reason to doubt what you have found (and cited)? Or do you have any question building upon what you have found?

Comment: I just find it strange that linked lists and double linked lists have the same Big O notation for insertion and finding, it seems like for the extra memory consumption the Big O would get better.

Comment: The main benefit of a double linked list is that the list is that a node in a doubly linked list is has a previous and next operation, while a linked list only has a next operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insert()` takes `O(1)` as you can add an element to the `head` of the linked list in constant time

`find()` takes `O(n)` time as in the worst case you need to traverse the list till you reach the `tail`

These apply for both single and doubly linked lists

Comment: there will be a change in constants for single and double and it doesn't affect big O.